# Android Studio how do I change layout_alignParentEnd for a view to be false programmatically?

Tags: android, kotlin

So suppose I have a textview called `tvPlaceholder` with the following property `android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"`. How would I go about setting this to be false in the code (Kotlin)? I know you can change things like visibility, text size, e.t.c. in the code but could not find a definitive answer for `layout_alignParentEnd`. I am also calling `tvPlaceholder` from a viewholder if that matters at all: `viewholder.tvPlaceholder`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When a view is added to a parent, it adds a LayoutParams object that defines any rules for laying it out.  You can get this object by calling getLayoutParams().  Each layout parent has their own layout params subclass, I'm assuming this is a relative layout.  So for a RelativeLayout, the LayourParams has a function removeRule that can do this.

```
val params = view.getLayoutParams() as RelativeLayout.LayoutParams
params.removeRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_END)
```